# how can i populate ref of own modal in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

how can i populate ref of own modal in mongoose . Is it possible to store own ref . when i try to populate it give RefrenceError.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const userSchema =  mongoose.Schema({
username: {
   type: String,
   required: true
},
fullname: {
   type: String,
   required: true
},
followers: [
  {
    type : mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
    ref : "User"
 }
],

});

const User = mongoose.model("User" , userSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.populate( "followers" )` works fine, even if you store a reference to the user itself in followers.

*This would be much easier if you at least show the code that you think throws the error.*

Here is a full working example, using your schema:

```
// Async/await to make things simple
async function run () {
  await mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost', { useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true })
  
  // Create, add the user to it's own followers, save.
  const user = new User({ username: 'aaa', fullname: 'bbb' })
  user.followers.push(user)
  await user.save()

  // Populate as usual
  const users = await User.find({})
    .populate('followers')
    .exec()

  // Stringify or else node will compact the output of deeply nested objects.
  console.log(JSON.stringify(users, null, 4))
}

run()
```